# Return JSON node onclick that matches the text in the link

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile, jsonp

The JS below returns a list of movie titles for me after parsing JSON. Each movie title node has more attributes and values not be displayed yet. When the user clicks the movie title in the list I want it to return the other values in that node match that title. How would I go about do that? Thanks.

I have posted a data example. The JS creates an HTML list of all the movie titles. As you can see there are several nodes of the same movie title, but with different "location." I want to be able to click on the movie title in the list and have it display all the different locations for the specific movie title in the HTML.

Here is a JS fiddle of what it is doing now. [JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pbpyrojust/4LBvh/)

JSON DATA:

```
    fl({
  "nodes" : [
{
  "node" : {
    "title" : "180",
    "ReleaseYear" : "2013",
    "Director" : "Jayendra",
    "Writer" : "Umarji Anuradha, Jayendra, Aarthi Sriram, &amp; Suba ",
    "Address" : "\n \n \n 555 Market St. \n San Francisco, CA\n United States\n \n \n See map: Google Maps \n \n",
    "Actor 1" : "Siddarth",
    "Actor 2" : "Nithya Menon",
    "Actor 3" : "Priya Anand",
    "Latitude" : "37.789952",
    "Longitude" : "-122.400158"
  }
},
{
  "node" : {
    "title" : "180",
    "ReleaseYear" : "2013",
    "Director" : "Jayendra",
    "Writer" : "Umarji Anuradha, Jayendra, Aarthi Sriram, &amp; Suba ",
    "Address" : "\n \n \n Epic Roasthouse (399 Embarcadero) \n San Francisco, CA\n United States\n \n \n See map: Google Maps \n \n",
    "Actor 1" : "Siddarth",
    "Actor 2" : "Nithya Menon",
    "Actor 3" : "Priya Anand",
    "Latitude" : "37.797677",
    "Longitude" : "-122.394339"
  }
},
{
  "node" : {
    "title" : "180",
    "ReleaseYear" : "2013",
    "Director" : "Jayendra",
    "Writer" : "Umarji Anuradha, Jayendra, Aarthi Sriram, &amp; Suba ",
    "Address" : "\n \n \n Mason &amp; California Streets (Nob Hill) \n San Francisco, CA\n United States\n \n \n See map: Google Maps \n \n",
    "Actor 1" : "Siddarth",
    "Actor 2" : "Nithya Menon",
    "Actor 3" : "Priya Anand",
    "Latitude" : "37.791556",
    "Longitude" : "-122.410766"
  }
}
  ]
})
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
    var sort_by = function(field, reverse, primer){
    var key = function(x) {return primer ? primer(x[field]) : x[field]};
    return function(a,b) {
        var A = key(a), B = key(b);
        return ((A < B) ? -1 : (A > B) ? +1 : 0) * [-1,1][+!!reverse];
    }
}

$.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'list',
    async: false,
    jsonpCallback: 'fl',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(data) {
        var tmp = [];
        for(var i=0;i<data.nodes.length;i++) {
            tmp.push(data.nodes[i].node);
        }
        tmp.sort(sort_by('title', true));
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        $('#film').append(div);
        $(div).attr( 'data-role', 'collapsible' );
        var heading = tmp[0]['title'][0];
        var h3 = document.createElement('h3');
        h3.innerHTML = heading;
        $(div).append(h3);
        h3=null;
        var title = '';
        for(var i=0;i<tmp.length;i++) {
            if(tmp[i]['title'] != title){ title=tmp[i]['title'];
                if(tmp[i]['title'][0] !== heading){
                    heading = tmp[i]['title'][0];
                    var div = document.createElement('div');
                    $('#film').append(div);
                    $(div).attr( 'data-role', 'collapsible' );
                    var h3 = document.createElement('h3');
                    h3.innerHTML = heading; 
                    $(div).append(h3);
                    h3=null;
                    var p = document.createElement('p');
                    $(div).append(p);
                }
                var film = "<a>"+tmp[i]['title']+"</a> <br />";
                $(p).append(film);
                film=null;
                //$("#sf_film").collapsibleset();
                $("#film").collapsibleset("refresh");
            }
        }
    }
});

function fl(json){
     console.log(json);   
}
```

Comment: could probably remove about 2/3 of the html parsing code. `$('<div>')` for example will create a new element. Doubt you want to `refresh` every time an element is appended in the `for` loop. WHat data do you want where. Can use `data()` method to store it on any element

Comment: I have an array, that will have multiple titles of the same movie, but different actors listed under each node. I want to display only the title once, but have all the other data displayed.

Comment: doesn't answer question of what gets clicked and what data you want displayed where whn it does get clicked. Post sample data and better explanation based on data and code

Comment: I have posted a data example. The JS creates an HTML list of all the movie titles. As you can see there are several nodes of the same movie title, but with different "location." I want to be able to click on the movie title in the list and have it display all the different locations for the specific movie title in the HTML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I have done this in the past is to load the array of objects from json into a single array objects, and then retrieved data from it using the array indices. My [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/FsspP/1/) shows an example of a fake ajax request which then loads it into an array, displays links with only the title in `displayLinks()`, and display more details using `showCast(movieId)` when you click on the link. Let me know if you have any questions.

**Update 1:**
I created an [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/FsspP/2/) that merges them by title. Where the first fiddle simple assigned `data` to `movies`, this one uses an additional array called `movieTitles` to hold unique movie titles, and uses a loop. The loop goes through each `data` element, checks to see if the `.title` value already exists in `movieTitles`. If it does exist, we use the index to access that movie in `movies` and there you can concatenate your other properties however you want. If it doesn't exists (`movieIndex` is -1), then we add the movie to `movies` and the movie title to `movieTitles`. Then loop till all elements in data have been assigned.
My example doesn't check for different capitalizations (so Batman and batman will show separately), but it's fairly easy and I didn't want spoil the fun and do all the work for you :)

Once again, let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: That is almost about what I am going for, but what if you have a movie node with the same title and you want to display the data and make sure the title doesn't display twice. Such as: 
data = [{
    'title': 'batman',
        'cast': 'bruce wayne'
}, {
 'title': 'batman',
        'cast': 'other actor'
}, {
    'title': 'true grit',
        'cast': 'john wayne'
}, {
    'title': 'tha carter',
        'cast': 'lil wayne'
}];

Comment: In the example you gave, would you ideally want to display bruce wayne, other actor, or both?

Comment: I would want to display both.

Comment: Updated it with a fiddle and some explanation :)

Comment: (Besides adding another batman entry to the json, there aren't any changes to the fiddle code until line 41)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed and this will really help me. I will let you know if I run into any more road bumps! Thanks!

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27906/discussion-between-justin-and-asifrc)

Answer (score -1):

Just parse the JSON string data with $.parseJSON. This will parse the string to a JS object.

If your JSON string have the following structure:

```
movies: {
    drama: [{ //An array of movies
        movieId: {
            title: 'title',
            rating: '',
            duration: ''
        }]
    },
    terror: [{ //An array of movies
        movieId: {
            title: 'title',
            rating: '',
            duration: ''
        }
    }]
}
```

Then in the click handler you can just access the corresponding object.

```
$(movie).on('click', function(){
    movieId = this.id;
    //Get the movie info from JSON parsed obj
    movieObj = movies.drama.movieId;
    // Append info to the DOM element
    $('list').append(movieObj.{attributeId});
})
```

Comment: -1 this answer is just wrong on several levels. There is no `JSON string` within success handler , javascript has no method `foreach` and if it did what would you be appending?

Comment: As in the example provided in the question, the succes handler is expecting a json string (determined by content-type). So, the JSON string is there. And yes, there is no foreach in JS I updated the code snippet to refer to $.each. Thanks.

Comment: no.. when dataType is `jsonp` jQuery will have already parsed the response ... is not a string. If it was a string how would OP be able to use array and object notation on it?